# Blogger Post Excerpt on Specific Word or Phase from Content

Tags: blogger

In my website( http://ehjbgdsdx.blogspot.in/ ), Post Title and Thumbnail is showing by this Code :

But I want to show the **Price** below post title. Kindly go to --> Xiaomi Redmi 4A Full Specification( http://ehjbgdsdx.blogspot.in/2017/05/test-post-1.html ) where the Price( Rs. 6,999/- ), I am wanting to take and show below Post Title in Main Page.

How can I do that?

Comment: It's easy to solved your problerm, if your provided your Blogger Template to me.

Answer (score 1):

You can show the price below post title by using Blogger labels for posts.

To do that open the post you mentioned above in post editor. Add the price i:e Rs. 6,999/- inside the labels box and update the post.

Now go to Blogger Dashboard>Theme>Edit HTML.

Press **CTRL + F** to open the search bar, now search for the `comment-bubble`. You may find some codes like this -

```
          <b:if cond='data:post.allowComments'> 
            <a class='comment-bubble' expr:href='data:post.addCommentUrl' expr:onclick='data:post.addCommentOnclick'><data:post.numComments/></a> 
      </b:if>
```

Replace the above codes with this

```
<div class='item_price'>
<b:loop values='data:post.labels' var='label'>
<b:if cond='data:label.name contains &quot;Rs&quot; or data:label.name contains &quot;₹&quot;'>
<span class='price'><data:label.name/></span>
</b:if>
</b:loop>
</div>
```

Now you should see the price below post title.